# Explicit formula for tournament sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, generating-functions, integer-sequences

I am looking for an explicit formula for a sequence. The sequence is generated as follows:

There is a tournament with $10$ teams. In the beginning, all teams have a 0-0 win-loss record. The teams are paired up, and when the first round concludes, $5$ of the teams have a 0-1 record and $5$ of the teams have a 1-0 record. The second round is arranged so that only teams with the same win-loss record are allowed to face each other, and when there are an odd number of teams having a certain win-loss record, the extra team from one win-loss record plays the extra team from the nearby win-loss record. This means that for the second round, four of the 0-1 teams are paired up with each other, $4$ of the 1-0 teams are paired up with each other, and there is one pairing between a 0-1 team and a 1-0 team. We also assume that when there is a pairing across different win-loss records, the team with the better record always wins. This means that at the end of round 2, there will be $3$ teams with a 0-2 record, there will be $4$ teams with a 1-1 record, and $3$ teams with a 2-0 record.

I am looking for an explicit formula giving the win-loss record distribution at round $r$. I am also looking for a general formula for $T$ teams (I used "10" earlier just for illustration purposes).

I have python code which explicitly calculates this sequence for $T$ teams and round $r$, but I would like a mathematical expression for this.

I have an explicit formula for the first $4$ rows using ceiling/floor functions, but the formula does not work beyond $4$ rows. I also have an explicit formula giving the win-loss record in the long term, but it only works after about $T^2$ rows.

In terms of problem solving techniques that I've tried, I've tried various generating series approaches. For example, for the case of $10$ teams, I wrote round $0$ as

$$f_0(x,y) = y^0 + y^1 + y^2 + ... + y^9$$

and round $1$ as

$$f_1(x,y) = y^0 + y^1 + y^2 + y^3 + y^ 4 + (y^5 + y^6 + y^7 + y^8 + y^9)x$$

and round $2$ as

$$f_2(x,y) = y^0 + y^1 + y^2 + (y^3 + y^4 + y^5 + y^6)x + (y^7 + y^8 + y^9)x^2$$

and so on. I don't have a method for moving from $f_k$ to $f_{k+1}$, but I have lots of near misses.

I have also tried using a probabilistic approach. I have started from several invariants, and I have a function that when minimized gives a (sometimes) close approximation. The invariants are as follows:

1. The number of teams $T$ does not change from round to round.
2. The number of total wins at each round is always $T r / 2$.
3. The win-loss record is symmetric around $r/2$.

These invariants restrict the number of possible choices for round $r$. I then took the choice that most nearly matches a binomial distribution (using the euclidean distance as a metric, although any similarity metric could work). This metric isn't best, since I believe the win-loss records become "less binomial" over time.

Another thing I tried was various kinds of graphing. I can post some graphs if requested.

I am open to any approach, I look forward to seeing your ideas.

**Updates and extra information**

Here are the first few terms of the sequence for $T=10$:

$$10$$

$$5, 5$$

$$3, 4, 3$$

$$2, 3, 3, 2$$

$$1, 3, 2, 3, 1$$

$$1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1$$

$$1, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1$$

$$1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1$$

$$1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1$$

$$1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1$$

$$...$$

Another clarification is that the number of teams $T$ must be even.

Also, I would like to add the formula for the long-term behavior of the sequences. The long-term behavior shows a 2-term repetition, and this repetition depends on the value of $T \pmod 8$. Here are the four cases:

Case 1. ($T \equiv 0 \pmod 8$): $1444...444...441$, $3444...4444....443$

Case 2. ($T \equiv 2 \pmod 8$): $3444...424...443$, $1444...4334....441$

Case 3. ($T \equiv 4 \pmod 8$): $3444...444...443$, $1444...4444....441$

Case 4. ($T \equiv 6 \pmod{8}$): $1444...424...441$, $3444...4334....443$

Note that I have left off the preceding $1000...$ and the trailing $...0001$, since the number of zeros can be easily calculated. Not also that the number of $4$s can be calculated easily from the original number of teams $T$.

Regarding the generating series idea previously, one thing I found is that if we have for example

$$f_2(x,y) = y^0 + y^1 + y^2 + (y^3 + y^4 + y^5 + y^6)x + (y^7 + y^8 + y^9)x^2$$

then we can calculate something very close to $f_3(x,y)$ by performing the following steps:

1. $$\frac{f_2(x,y) + f_2(x,-y)}{2} = y^0 + y^2 + (y^4 + y^6)x + (y^8)x^2$$
2. $$\frac{f_2(x,y) - f_2(x,-y)}{2} \cdot x = y^1 x + (y^3 + y^5) x^2 + (y^7 + y^9) x^3$$
3. $$\widetilde{f}_3(x,y) = \frac{f_2(x,y) + f_2(x,-y)}{2} + \frac{f_2(x,y) - f_2(x,-y)}{2} \cdot x = y^0 + y^2 + (y^1 + y^4 + y^6)x + (y^3 + y^5 + y^8)x^2 + (y^7 + y^9)x^3$$

which when evaluated at $y = 1$ gives the correct sequence $2,3,3,2$. It is not exactly correct, since the $y$ terms are no longer ordered in terms of exponents, so this process is not repeatable unless we improve on it somehow.

**Another Update**

Let's add a variant to the original rules. The variant will be called "underdog", whereas the original rules will be called "overdog". The "overdog" rules stipulate that the team with the higher win-loss record will always win when it crosses over and faces a team with a lower win-loss ratio; in contrast, the "underdog" rules stipulate that the team with the lower win-loss ratio will win.

Let's call the overdog sequence with $T$ teams the sequence $O(T)$, and each term in the sequence will be identified as $O_{r,w}(T)$ where $r$ denotes the round and $w$ denotes the number of wins at that round. For the underdog variant, we define $U(T)$ and $U_{r,w}(T)$ in the same way.

I just discovered the following properties:

$$O(2^k + 2) = U(2^k) + O(2)$$

$$O(2^k + 4) = U(2^k) + U(2) + O(2)$$

This is helpful since $U(2^k)$ and $O(2^k)$ are easy to calculate for $k$ rows, and $O(2)$ and $U(2)$ are easily calculated for all rows.

I'm wondering if we can use the binary representation of $T$ and some kind of summing procedure to improve the number of rows that we can directly calculate. It would be fascinating to try to reduce $O(T)$ and $U(T)$ to the sum of terms of the form $U(2^K)$ or $O(2^K)$ for any arbitrarily large $K >> 0$. This would give us a way to calculate arbitrarily many rows for any $T$.

**Correction to Previous Update**

I should edit my previous update to be more precise. The powers of two were a bit of a red herring — all that matters is $T \pmod{4}$. Here are the updated relations:

1. $O(4k + 2) = U(4k) + O(2)$.
2. $U(4k + 2) = U(4k) + U(2)$.
3. $O(4k + 4) = U(4k) + U(2) + O(2)$.

This means that the problem is essentially reduced to finding $U(4k)$ instead of finding $U(2k)$. Not much of a reduction, but it's progress!

Comment: Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4647897.

Comment: @StevenClark Yes, thanks for linking

Comment: Respectfully, that is far too soon. A minimum wait of a few days, if not a week, would be more appropriate delay before cross-posting here.

Comment: @DavidRoberts My apologies, I am pretty new, I will wait the appropriate time from now on.

Comment: @Jackson no problems! Thanks for understanding, and wish you luck with getting the answer you need :-)

Comment: In essence you get something similar to the binomial recurrence, $f(n,k) = \left\lfloor \frac{f(n -1,k -1)}2 \right\rceil + \left\lfloor \frac{f(n -1,k)}2 \right\rceil$ where the complication is that the choice between floor and ceiling depends on the parity of the count of odd values in $f(n -1,0)\ldots f (n-1,k-1)$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Exactly, that's a great framing of the problem. As you've suggested, it is difficult to determine a formula to get from one row to the next due to the floor/ceiling complication. The dream is to be able to determine an exact formula that directly gives us the win-loss record some arbitrary number of rows down from the current row.

Comment: Say, $\sigma(n)=1$ if odd, $0$ otherwise, then the end terms $a^{r}_0=\lceil \frac{a^{r-1}_0}{2}\rceil$, 2nd end $a^{r}_1=\lfloor \frac{a^{r-1}_0}{2}\rfloor + \lceil \frac{a^{r-1}_1-\sigma(a_0)}{2} \rceil$, 3rd end $a^{r}_2=\lfloor  \frac{a^{r-1}_1-\sigma(a_0)}{2} \rfloor + \sigma(a_0) + \lceil \frac{a^{r-1}_2-\sigma(\frac{a^{r-1}_1-\sigma(a_0)}{2})}{2}\rceil$, here, $r$ is the $r$-th round..... and so on. So, it's pretty complicated.

Comment: @AlapanDas Your formula for $a^{r}_{0}$ looks great. I am wondering, what does $a_0$ mean in your other formulas? I'm guessing it either means $a^{r}_{0}$ or $a^{r-1}_{0}$, but I want to be sure.

Comment: @Jackson, sorry for the mistake. In other formulas, it's $a^{r-1}_0$. All the terms are from previous row. Btw I think might be of use to think in terms of binary representation.

Comment: @AlapanDas Thanks for the clarification, I understand the formulas now, thanks for the help. The binary representation idea is interesting too, let me know if you have further ideas in that direction.

Comment: fascinating question. I will think about it.

Comment: Now up to version 12 of this question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's right, I'm not giving up on this problem! It's just for recreation, but it's surprisingly difficult and therefore worthwhile. Plus it is very practical, since this is how tournaments work in some places.